# Python pulling html table from webpage

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

The table [on this page](https://www.ncaa.com/rankings/basketball-women/d1/ncaa-womens-basketball-net-rankings) needs to be scraped daily. We are trying to keep the scraping as simple (robust) as possible so there are no issues with the code running on our server. Would like to steer clear of Selenium:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

page_list = pd.read_html('https://www.ncaa.com/rankings/basketball-women/d1/ncaa-womens-basketball-net-rankings')
page_df = pd.DataFrame(page_list) 
# won't convert to df (ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 356, 9)

r = requests.get('https://www.ncaa.com/rankings/basketball-women/d1/ncaa-womens-basketball-net-rankings')
# not sure what to do with response
```

`page_list` is close but it is a 3-dimensional list. How can we get this into a 2-dimensional list, or into a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do `page_df = pd.DataFrame(page_list[0])`. Can actually simply this to `page_df = page_list[0]`:

```
page_list = pd.read_html('https://www.ncaa.com/rankings/basketball-women/d1/ncaa-womens-basketball-net-rankings')
page_df = page_list[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

`pd.read_html` doesn't return a DataFrame but a list of dataframes. Use `page_list[0]` to get the first dataframe:

```
page_df = pd.DataFrame(page_list[0])
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

> Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.